# \textbullet in Same font

Tags: fonts, symbols

If I use any font as my base font, e.g., `AGaramond`, then if I use the tag `\textbullet` then the bullet should come from `AGaramond` family only, how can I achieve this. Note that I am using `MikTeX V2.9` and converted fonts from `OTF` to MikTeX compatibility using `autoinst` option.

Hope this may not require `MWE`, if requires I'll post it...

Comment: Please add an compilable short code resulting in your issue (you should know with your reputation :-( )

Comment: you mention you are using miktex but that's not relevant really (texlive would be the same) I assume (but you don't say) that you are using pdftex. (Is there any reason not to use luatex or xetex if you are using OTF fonts, as then you could just use • directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using LaTeX, dvips and ps2pdf to generate the output, as I need to generate using some specific Distiller options, e.g., need to incorporate the Sheridan options in PDF file...

Comment: You just need to make sure you have a TS1 encoded version of your font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops...sorry, I am using T1 fontencoding not TS1, I missed to mention it in my post...

Comment: No. T1 hasn't got a bullet, you need a TS1 encoded version of the font in addition to the T1 encoded font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T1 encoding does not have a bullet, so in that case you need to use the TS1 symbol companion font encoding (which `\textbullet` will do by default) so you just need to ensure that you have a TS1 encoded subset of your OTF font.

Alternatively you could use LY1 encoding instead of TS1 in which case there is a bullet, which again `\textbullet` will use by default.